# Why both value type and reference type

Tags: c#

I know the difference b/w value type and reference type. But why we need both? We can use reference type instead of value type.

Comment: when you are asking about using a reference type instead of a value type, are you asking about designing objects as classes instead of structs?  Or are you just asking in general "why are there reference types and value types instead of just a single type"

Comment: I would like to point out that the correct answer for this should have two parts.  It should show why there are not just value types, and why there are not just reference types.

Answer (score 3):

You could in fact construct a language that knows only reference types. Value types are there mainly for efficiency reasons. It is more efficient to implement numeric types and the bool type, for instance, as value types.

Comment: Is it possible to construct a language that knows only value types?

Comment: Hmm... I suddenly realized that maybe C is a value-only Turing-complete language?

Comment: In C you can dynamically allocate memory. What you get is a pointer to this memory block which can, for instance, contain an array.

Comment: Yeah, but I think even pointers in C are still value typed, not reference. It is just that their values are memory addresses, which have to be explicitly dereferenced with `*`  to access the "real" target.

Answer (score 2):

To understand value types, one must first understand the concepts of storage locations and reference types.

Objects generally use fields to represent their state, and running code generally uses variables and parameters to express its state.  Such things, as well as array slots, are collectively referred to as "storage locations".

A reference-type storage location holds an object identifier, or else a special "null" value.  Such storage locations don't actually hold objects--just identifiers which can be used to quickly locate them.  A storage locations which is declared to be of interface types (e.g. `ICollection<T>`) holds a reference to an object which is known to implement the specified interface (or else "null").

Copying a reference-type storage location simply makes a copy of the identifier.  It has no effect whatsoever on the physical state of the referred-to-object.  Conceptually, this may seem simple, but it can be tricky.  The problem is that while a reference-type storage location physically holds an object identifier, semantically such storage locations can be used to capture any of the following aspects of an object:

1. Its identity (particularly as it relates to other storage locations that hold a reference to the same object)

   Its immutable characteristics

   Its mutable characteristics

Physically, of course, a reference-type storage location holds the identity of an object.  Nonetheless, such locations are often used semantically to hold other information.  Consider, for example, that an object `George` holds a field `thing` of type `ICollection<integer>`.  Such a storage location will hold a reference to a collection of integers, which will allow them to be enumerated, and may or may not allow things to be added or removed.  How is the state of `George` affected by the contents of `thing`?  It could affec the state in a number of ways.

1. `George` may expect that `thing` holds the identity of some sort of immutable collection--something which will always return the same set of numbers.  If there happen to exist several immutable collections that contain the same numbers, the state of `George` will not be affected by which of those collections is identified by `thing`.  Its state just depends upon the immutable contents.

   `George` might have stored in `thing` a reference to a mutable list which it created, and which it doesn't share with any other object.  `George` expects that the list referred to by `thing` will hold whatever it puts there, and nothing else.  In this scenario, `George` wouldn't care if its collection were replaced by another which had the same mutable characteristics.  It's simply interested in the mutable contents of that collection.

   It's possible that `George` doesn't care about the contents of the collection referred to by `thing`, but that its job is to add things to that collection for the benefit of some other object which does care about the contents.  In this scenario, the identity of the collection is what matters--it's imperative that `thing` hold a reference to the same collection as the object which is expecting to see the things `George` adds.

   Finally, it's possible that George is interested in both the mutable contents and the identity of the object referred to by `thing`.  This scenario would apply if `George` were the object that was expecting its collection to receive items from some other object.

Note that in all four of the above cases, the storage location had exactly the same type.  Nothing about the declaration of that storage location would indicate what aspects of it were important.  Note further that a lot of the complexity stems from the fact that a class reference will often encapsulate both mutable state and identity.  If a storage location didn't encapsulate a concept of identity, things would be much simpler.

Enter value types.  If one has a storage location whose type is a value-type struct like:

```
struct Point3d
{
  public double X,Y,Z;
  Point3d(double X, double Y, double Z)
  {
    this.X =  X; this.Y = Y; this.Z = Z;
  }
}
```

that storage location will hold the contents of that struct's fields (in this case, the three `double` values in fields `X`, `Y`, and `Z`.  If a class has a field of that type, the state represented by that field will be the three numbers held therein.  Unlike class objects, where equivalence may or may not depend upon content, struct types have no such ambiguity.  Two exposed-field structs (sometimes called PODS--Plain Old Data Structures) are equivalent if they are of the same type, and if their corresponding fields are equivalent.

Although classes can do many things which value types cannot, such power can create confusion, ambiguity, and complexity.  For example, if one wishes to take a "snapshot" of the state of a class, one must know which aspects of its fields are important to its state.  If the state of a class object `Larry` depends upon the mutable state of an object `Mike` to which it holds a reference, then taking a snapshot of the `Larry`'s state will require taking a snapshot of `Mike`'s state as well (and storing a reference to that snapshot in all field or fields of the duplicate `Larry` where the original `Larry` would have held references to `Mike`).  By contrast, copying an exposed-field struct is easy.  Just copy all its fields.

Exposed-field structs make wonderful data holders, except for a couple of limitations:

1. The only way that a struct (whether it has exposed fields or private field) can hold a variable amount of data is by holding a reference to an object which holds the data and will never change.  Since there's no way a struct can know whether one of its fields holds the only extant reference to an object, there's no way it can know whether any references are held by things that expect them not to change.

   While it is possible for a struct to modify itself within its own methods, compilers sometimes execute struct methods on copies of structures rather than the originals.  While this is commonly cited as a reason to avoid mutable structures, such a problem only affects structures which modify *themselves*.  It does not affect structures which expose their fields to direct outside modification.

Suppose the state of a class depends upon 5,000 3-d points.  If the `Point3d` type is going to be a class, one must either have the `Point3d` type be immutable, or else keep the only extant references to 5,000 instances of it.  If the `Point3d` type is immutable, then any time one wishes to alter any aspect of the state indicated thereby, one must create a whole new `Point3d` instance and abandon the old one.  If the type is mutable, then any time one wishes to expose the coordinates from a point to outside code, one must copy the `X`, `Y`, and `Z` values.  Neither option seems very pleasant.

Making `Point3d` an exposed-field struct eliminates both those problems.  Since a `Point3d` is nothing more than an `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, an array of 5,000 `Point3d` objects will simply hold 15,000 numbers.  Exposing any `Point3d` to the outside world will automatically copy the three associated numbers.  If one wishes to change e.g. the `Z` coordinate of a `Point` without disturbing the others, no problem--if the `Point` is stored in an array, one can add 9.8 to the Z coordinate of array slot 4 by

```
  MyArray[4].Z += 9.8;
```

If the `Point` is stored in some other type of collection, things are a little more awkward, but not too bad:

```
  Point3d temp = MyArray[4];
  temp.Z += 9.8;
  MyArray[4] = temp;
```

Much more convenient than if `Point3d` was a class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe one of the differences you missed is that value types are allocated in the Stack and reference types in the Heap. This makes a big performance difference (since one is a pointer accessed indirectly and the other is the value itself).

**EDIT:**
My mention of heap and stack is wrong, as shown in the comments. The correct statement should be as Eric Lippert said [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx):

*"in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."*

Comment: Have you read [this: The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) or [this: The Stack Is An Implementation Detail 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) and [this: The Stack Is An Implementation Detail 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx)

Comment: This is not correct. You can store a value type inside an object that is on the heap. See Eric Lippert's article [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) and [Part Two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx).

Comment: Nope, I hadn't. Thanks, always good to learn something new. Now, given that MS usually states this as well, maybe it's just that for simplicity reasons it's easier to explain it as "it always goes in the stack" rather than "it <can> go in the stack stack except in these N situations", and that's why some of us might have the details wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Value Type stores `value` directly.

For example:

```
//I and J are both of type int
I = 20;
J = I;
```

Here, `int` is a value type, which means that the above statements will results in two locations in memory. For each instance of value type separate memory is allocated and stored in a Stack. It Provides Quick Access, because of value located on stack.

Reference Type stores `reference` to the value.

For example:

```
Vector X, Y; //Object is defined. (No memory is allocated.)
X = new Vector(); //Memory is allocated to Object. //(new is responsible for allocating memory.)
X.value = 30; //Initialising value field in a vector class.
Y = X; //Both X and Y points to same memory location. //No memory is created for Y.
Console.writeline(Y.value); //displays 30, as both points to same memory
Y.value = 50;
Console.writeline(X.value); //displays 50.
```

**Note:** If a variable is reference it is possible to indicate that it does not refer to any object by setting its value to null.

Reference type are stored on Heap and it provides comparatively slower access, as value located on heap.

Comment: Value types are stored in stack. Please correct the last sentence.

Comment: Aside from the obvious error @VahanHakobyan already pointed out, this answer only explains the difference between values and references, but not cover at all why both types are used.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way I can think to explain it is:

A value type represents a unchanging value.  No matter which object it is `1` will always be `1`, and `3.14159265359` will always be `3.14159265359`. And `8/18/2012 17:23 UTC` represents an exact moment in time that is always the same.  Therefore I can create a thousand different `int` or `DateTime` objects with these values and they always will be exactly the same, no matter where they are and how they are used.

However, a reference type is not always the same, even when the specifications are the same.  I could build a house at a given address, then give the plans to a friend who could build another house with exactly the same specifications, same size, even the same landscaping and same size yard, but no matter how hard you try to make them look the same, the 2 houses still will never be exactly the same.