# Why are ValueTypes in Object Oriented Languages like C# ,Java

Tags: c#, java, oop

Hi I just want to know for knowledge why there are **Value Types** in C# or Java . Why they all are not **Reference Types**?. I can see two reasons for my own:
1)Performance: All commonly used DataTypes are Value types since Value Types have single round where as Reference Types have two rounds first to stack and then to heap.So performance can be the reason. 2)Assigning Values.Any help will be highly appericiated.Thanks

Comment: What makes you think they're contradictory concepts?  You can have object oriented design on a value type.  Why shouldn't they have value types?

Comment: "All commonly used DataTypes are Value types" - really? Like `String`?

Comment: I disagree with the *close* vote, as this question can definitely have "answers [that are] supported by facts, references, or specific expertise". The question was already discussed - though not really answered - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020544/why-both-value-type-and-reference-type).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."  It won't solicit polling so much, but all of the rest of it applies.  It's fundamentally a subjective question, rather than an objective question with a "correct" answer, and so it doesn't belong on SO.

Comment: [On Java 10, there is speculation of removing primitive data types and move towards 64-bit addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_10).

Comment: @Servy: So, the conclusion is that question on design rationales behind existing language features are generally off-topic on SO, even though answers to them can be unambiguously be supported by references to whatever documents how the language designers made the decision?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper He's not asking about a specific, concrete language, he's asking about object oriented languages in general, like [...].  So unless you plan to offer such information for every single OO language in the world (which would be inappropriate for SO for other unrelated, but hopefully obvious, reasons), it's not answerable.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Note the [citation needed].  Just seeing it on Wikipedia and nowhere else doesn't really mean much...

Comment: @Servy: Ok, that's true. Though it doesn't quite explain why the other question, which *is* C#-specific, was closed with the same reason.

Comment: @Servy : I am working in C# ,so my question is for C# . But I have also read that Java's primitive Types are value Types .All Types are of Reference Types except of enums,structs or primitive Types so its for sure that there are some solid reasons for having different behavior for these few Types.

Comment: @Jon Skeet String may not be a value type but it certainly behaves like it, which I suspect is more to the point of the question.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, really? Trusting it from Wikipedia with no citation?

Comment: @Jeff No, strings do *not* behave like value types, because they're not value types, they're references types, and always act just like reference types.  Remember, immutability and reference semantics are entirely different concepts.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Yes Jon , I mean DataTypes like String ,int,double,enums..

Comment: @ethicallogics: Do you understand that `String` *isn't* a value type though? That's what I meant...

Comment: @Servy It is not a value type but it does behave like one because it's immutable.

Comment: @ethicallogics: Um, I see no leg-pulling. What are you referring to?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I think they were right to close it since it's a complicated and subjective question.

Comment: @ethicallogics, if we talk about C#, a value type is still an object on your heap. you can't declare variables on your stack as in C/C++. A value type is just a "special object" that can not be mutated. Thus, if you assign the variable to another variable like `int a = b;` then the actual value is copied. You were asking for a link. maybe msdn is a nice start? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx. If anything in this comment is incorrect than I hope somebody in the conversation will correct me.

Comment: @Jeff Yes the question is contradictory and even in books/internet there is no exact reply to this.So I came here because this is the place to get best answers

Comment: @bas: Um, no. Within a method, a value type will *usually* be stack-allocated. It depends on the specific context though - it's an implementation detail for the most part.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah right. That I honestly didn't know. Sorry for the incorrect info and thx for the lesson.

Comment: @Jeff As I said before, mutability and references semantics are entirely independant concepts.  You can have a mutable or immutable value type, as well as a mutable or immutable reference type.  That you can't mutate an object in no way makes it a value type, or even like a value type.

Comment: @Sevry Yup, I understand all that.  In my opinion the CLR still treats strings like value types.  The only reason they aren't is because of implementation stuff.  See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of it is performance but a bigger reason is the resulting behavior.  You tend to think of integers (for example) as immutable value types.  However, if you're dealing with an object, you would be surprised if updating a field in that object wasn't maintained in a calling method because you were modifying a copy.

Comment: You can have an immutable class.  You don't need to have value types in order to have immutable objects.

Comment: Right, I don't think that's the issue though.  The issue is that value types are unboxed by default.  It would be painful if you had to say treat this int as unboxed today!

Comment: If the object is mutable then reference vs value semantics are *very* important.  If it's immutable then those semantics can't ever be observed bar performance.